# How to get derived data in QGIS or R?

Tags: qgis, postgis, r

I am struggling to get derived data from a shapefile. In the attribute table of the shapefile, I can see just the `id`, `initialdat` and `finaldate`.
[image]

Does anyone have a good solution to get the derived data in R or QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

That "derived data" is derived from the location you clicked on in QGIS.

It does not exist in the Shapefile as such, since it really depends on your click location.

If you can narrow down which aspects of the derived data you want (eg the areas of all features) then you can probably find QGIS processing functions that will add them as new attribute columns.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Spacedman!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Spacedman's answer, here are a few processing functions you might want:

- `Export/Add Geometry  Columns` - this processing function adds columns with polygon area and perimeter measurements. Find it in the Vector menu or Processing Toolbox.
- Use the geometry functions in the Field Calculator to add columns with other geometric calculations. I provided *a few examples* below. Read the built-in help inside the Field Calculator to see all the options available.

  - `x(centroid($geometry))` → the X coordinate of the feature's centroid (note that for a concave polygon the centroid is not always inside the polygon)
  - `y(centroid($geometry))` → the Y coordinate of the feature's centroid
  - `$area` → the area of the polygon *calculated using the ellipsoid and measurement units of the QGIS project*
  - `area($geometry)` - gives the area of the polygon *in the CRS of the layer*
  - `num_points($geometry)` → number of vertices in the current feature

Comment: It works very well! Thanks